# Simple Functional Equation $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\cdot(-a)+f(a)=-ab$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Compute all real-valued functions $f$ so that the line between any two points on the graph $f$ intersects the $x$-axis at the product of those two points' $x$-coordinates times $-1$.

(if we do some simplifing, we just need all functions so that $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\cdot(-a)+f(a)=-ab$ for all points $a$ and $b$)

We can immediately see that $f(x)=x^2$ works, and we can also see that $f(0)=0$. If we assume $x$ to be a polynomial and let $f(x)=x\cdot Q(x)$, then we can do some manipulation and see that $\frac{Q(a)-Q(b)}{a-b}=1$, from which we see that $Q(x)=x+c$ an we can easily find $f(x)=x^2$ is the only solution.

But what if $f$ is not a polynomial (and we cant suppose $f(x)=x\cdot Q(x)$)? Looking at the Taylor Polynomial of $f$, it would appear that this case fails too, but I cannot rigorously prove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A common trick is to consider the difference of any two such functions.  In this case, let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ both satisfy your functional equation.  Then we can determine that $\displaystyle \frac{h(a)-h(b)}{a-b}(-a)+h(a) = 0$, and hence $ah(b) = bh(a)$ for all $a$ and $b$.  Substituting in $1$ for $b$, we get $h(a) = ah(1)$, and thus $h(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$. Since $f(x) = x^2$ is a solution, all solutions must therefore be polynomials of the form $f(x) = x^2 + cx$.

Edit:  Originally this said to apply the OP's earlier work at this point, but all such functions $f(x) = x^2+cx$ are in fact solutions to the functional equation in question, as one can check by substituting.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\cdot(-a)+f(a)=-ab$ is equivalent to $bf(a)-af(b)=ab(a-b)$. Put $a=0,b\neq 0$ to get $f(0)=0$. Then choose $a$ constant such that $f(a)=c\neq 0$ (constant zero function does not work here) and get
$$ bc-af(b)=a^2b-b^2a$$
divide by $a$ (which is not zero) and you have $f(b)=b^2+bc/a-ab$, but $a,c$ are constants so $f(b)=b^2+kb$. We verify and this works.

---

Note: verification at the end is important. At the International Mathematical Olympiad (the top competition for students before university) you lose a point by default if you do not verify the solution of a functional equation in the end.

Comment: +1, I like the semantic ambiguity of the last sentence: It sounds like the reason it's important is the fact that you lose points at the Olympiad, not the other way around.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a $\frac{bc}{a}$?

Comment: @NickKidman: You're right :) You don't need to verify in order not to lose points. What I wanted to say is that even at high levels verification is considered important. It doesn't mater that it is a trivial computation. You might find that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @chubakueno: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: I'm not sure if you understood what I mean. I ment that saying it's important, followed by the sentence about it's relevance in math competitions, makes it sounds like the verification is important *because* of it's value in math competitions. (I should add that I might just have less premises than you here: If or if it's not importantant in math competition is, for me, a priori independend of anything - they are rules of a game and could just as well be made up).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight variant of Beni Bogosel's answer.

The given functional equation implies $bf(a)-af(b)=ab(a-b)$ for *all* $a$ and $b$, so in particular if $a=x$ and $b=1$, in which case it becomes $f(x)-xf(1)=x(x-1)$, which can be rewritten as $f(x)=x(x+c)$ where $c=f(1)-1$.  So *if* there is a function satisfying the functional equation, then it must be of the form $f(x)=x(x+c)$, which, of course, has been verified to work.